# bad three js performance with raycasters

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

so i have been experimenting with ray casting in three js but i ran into terrible performance issues in Firefox and chrome (but something else is causing chromes camera to rubber band even though its a small local game) anyways when i add this code to the animate loop

```
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(sceneObjects);

                if (intersects.length > 0) {
                       var firstIntersectedObject  = intersects[0];
                       console.log(intersects[0].object.userData)
                       console.log(intersects[0].object.userData.glow )
                       if (intersects[0].object.userData.glow === 'true'){
                           console.log("GLOW")
                       }else{
                           console.log("NO!")
                       }
                       //intersects[0].object.material.wireframe = true
                       // this will give you the first intersected Object if there are multiple.
                    }
```

my game starts to get all laggy and i have no idea why any pointers

Comment: How large is `sceneObjects`? Is it really necessary to do that for EVERY frame (up to 60 times per second)?

Comment: There a Max of 20 objects in there.. my goal for doing this is to make an item glow if it has that in the object.userdata. I'm trying to make it to where I can pick up objects off the ground

Comment: The complexity of the meshes is also a factor, but it sounds like you could reduce the number of times this code runs per second. You could create a counter which increments with every frame. Every time it hits (for example) 30, reset it to 0, and run your raycast code. You may have to tweak the number a little, but you should find it's still reasonably responsive without causing as much lag as what you're currently seeing.

Comment: +1 to @TheJim01's suggestion. You could also create an array containing only objects that have `userData.glow`, and raycast on that, if you're not going to do anything with the others anyway.

Comment: @TheJim01 +1 this is exactly what I do with my code. In my app I only raycast at most every 50ms, and the next raycast can't be fired until the last one completed + 50ms. Also it only raycasts on mouse move, click, double click. I'll edit my code down and post an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't raycast on **every** frame, instead you should have it raycast on an interval. You can use `setTimeout` or `setInterval` or check the timing in the update loop.

```
onUpdate() {
    // Code that runs once per frame

    // Check that we've waited long enough to raycast
    if (Date.now() - this.lastRaycast > this.raycastInterval && this.qRaycast) {
        this.handleRaycast();
        this.lastRaycast = Date.now();
        this.qRaycast = false;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame( () => this.onUpdate() );
}
```

I also only queue up raycasts when the mouse moves (no reason to keep raycasting if the mouse isn't moving) and because I have panning in my project, I disable raycast during panning movements to prevent any jitter during movement.

```
// Event Handlers
// Record mouse position for raycast
onMouseMove(e) {
    this.mouse.x = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    this.mouse.y = -((e.clientY - 50) / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    // If we are panning, don't queue a raycast
    this.qRaycast = !this.mouseState.held;
}

// My app has panning, and we don't wanna keep raycasting during pan
onMouseDown(e) {
    this.mouseState.lastClick = Date.now();
    this.mouseState.clicked = false;
    this.mouseState.held = true;
}

onMouseUp(e) {
    this.mouseState.held = false;
}
```

then we handle the raycast:

```
// Like lasers, but virtual.
handleRaycast() {
    let hits = null;
    let hitcount = 0;
    if (UI.raycast && meshObj) {
        this.raygun.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
        hits = this.raygun.intersectObject(meshObj, false);
        hitcount = hits.length;
    }

    if (hitcount > 0) {
        // Do stuff with the raycast here
    }
}
```

If you are still having performance issues, then you might wanna look into breaking down that loop function so that after XXms it breaks to let the UI update, and then continues updating on the next frame:

For example, I sort through all hits and find the point that is closest to the mouse:

```
// Optimization
let startTime = 0;
let maxTime = 75; // max time in ms
let dist = 1;
let hitIndex;
let i = 0;

function findClosest() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        function loop() {
            startTime = performance.now();
            while (i < hitcount) {
                // Break loop after maxTime
                let currentTime = performance.now();
                if ((currentTime - startTime) > maxTime) {
                    console.log('Loop exceeded max time: ' + 
                        (currentTime - startTime).toFixed(3) );
                    startTime = currentTime;
                    break;
                }

                // I am finding the raycast point that is closest to the cursor
                dist = hits[i].distanceToRay;
                if (dist < smallestDist) {
                    smallestDist = dist;
                    smallestPointIndex = hits[i].index;
                }
                i++;
            }

            if (i < hitcount) {
                // Allow the UI to update, then loop
                setTimeout(loop, 1);
            } else {
                resolve(smallestPointIndex);
            }
        }
        loop();
    });
}

findClosest().then(result => {
    // do something with the result here
}
```

Also the comments were good suggestions also to reduce the number of objects you are raycasting to.

Comment: Amazing answer thank you for taking your time to help me

Comment: Happy to help! I spent a long time trying to optimize my raycasting operation because in my project there are times it's possible to be raycasting to 1,000+ points, which can be understandably very slow. Using the above + some tricks by reducing the raycasting threshold, there is no noticeable lag from raycasting on most devices.